# Cannot store Object in List<Object> with method from package?

Tags: java, object, methods, intellij-idea, javafx

So someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here. My goal is to add the Motorcycle to mInventory (which I have created and imported from a separate package). However, I continue getting errors in my code. I took the Java course from Treehouse and now I'm trying to get out there and get my hands dirty using IntelliJ, but I can't help but feel like they really just threw us out there without really explaining how IntelliJ works. Anyone got some advice for me???

Here's Main.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/sample.fxml"));

        primaryStage.setTitle("Store Motorcycle");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here's my Controller class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import sample.com.gardnerwebideas.Inventory;
import sample.com.gardnerwebideas.Motorcycle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Controller {

    @FXML private TextField bikeYear;
    @FXML private TextField bikeMake;
    @FXML private TextField bikeModel;
    @FXML private TextField bikeColor;
    @FXML private TextField bikePrice;

    private Inventory mInventory = new Inventory();

    public void userCreateBike(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Motorcycle motorcycle = newMotorcycle();
        System.out.printf("Adding: %s", motorcycle);
        mInventory.addMotorcycle(motorcycle);
    }

    public Motorcycle newMotorcycle() {
        String year = bikeYear.getText();
        String make = bikeMake.getText();
        String model = bikeModel.getText();
        String color = bikeColor.getText();
        String price = bikePrice.getText();
        return new Motorcycle(year, make, model, color, price);
    }

}
```

Here's my Inventory class:

```
package sample.com.gardnerwebideas;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Inventory {

    private List<Motorcycle> mInventory;

    public Inventory() {
        mInventory = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addMotorcycle(Motorcycle motorcycle) {
        mInventory.add(motorcycle);
    }

    public int getInventoryCount() {
        return mInventory.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Inventory{" +
                "mInventory=" + mInventory +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And finally the Motorcycle class:

```
package sample.com.gardnerwebideas;

public class Motorcycle {

    private String mYear;
    private String mMake;
    private String mModel;
    private String mColor;
    private String mPrice;

    public Motorcycle(String year, String make, String model, String color, String price) {
        mYear = year;
        mMake = make;
        mModel = model;
        mColor = color;
        mPrice = price;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return mYear;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return mMake;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return mModel;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return mColor;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return mPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Motorcycle:" +
                "Year: " + mYear + "\n" +
                "Make: " + mMake + "\n" +
                "Model: " + mModel + "\n" +
                "Color: " + mColor + "\n" +
                "Price: " + mPrice + "\n";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Motorcycle that = (Motorcycle) o;

        if (mYear != null ? !mYear.equals(that.mYear) : that.mYear != null) return false;
        if (mMake != null ? !mMake.equals(that.mMake) : that.mMake != null) return false;
        if (mModel != null ? !mModel.equals(that.mModel) : that.mModel != null) return false;
        if (mColor != null ? !mColor.equals(that.mColor) : that.mColor != null) return false;
        return !(mPrice != null ? !mPrice.equals(that.mPrice) : that.mPrice != null);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = mYear != null ? mYear.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (mMake != null ? mMake.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (mModel != null ? mModel.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (mColor != null ? mColor.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (mPrice != null ? mPrice.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>

<GridPane alignment="CENTER"
          stylesheets="/css/style.css"
          xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
          fx:controller="sample.Controller">

   <children>

       <Text styleClass="title"
             text="Add a motorcycle:"
             GridPane.columnSpan="2"
             GridPane.halignment="CENTER"
             GridPane.rowIndex="0" />

       <Text styleClass="textTitle"
             text="Year:"
             GridPane.columnIndex="0"
             GridPane.rowIndex="1" />

       <TextField fx:id="bikeYear"
                  GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                  GridPane.rowIndex="1" />

       <Text styleClass="textTitle"
             text="Make:"
             GridPane.columnIndex="0"
             GridPane.rowIndex="2" />

       <TextField fx:id="bikeMake"
                  alignment="TOP_LEFT"
                  GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                  GridPane.rowIndex="2" />

       <Text styleClass="textTitle"
             text="Model:"
             GridPane.columnIndex="0"
             GridPane.rowIndex="3" />

       <TextField fx:id="bikeModel"
                  GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                  GridPane.rowIndex="3" />

       <Text styleClass="textTitle"
             text="Color:"
             GridPane.columnIndex="0"
             GridPane.rowIndex="4" />

       <TextField fx:id="bikeColor"
                  GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                  GridPane.rowIndex="4" />

       <Text styleClass="textTitle"
             text="Price:"
             GridPane.columnIndex="0"
             GridPane.rowIndex="5" />

       <TextField fx:id="bikePrice"
                  GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                  GridPane.rowIndex="5" />

       <Button onAction="#userCreateBike"
               styleClass="button"
               text="Submit"
               GridPane.columnSpan="2"
               GridPane.halignment="CENTER"
               GridPane.rowIndex="6" />

   </children>

</GridPane>
```

If any of that is unclear let me repeat it... what is causing me issues is the line: 
`mInventory.addMotorcycle(motorcycle);`
Apart from that, my code works. It gets info from my TextFields and will even print it out to the console... but it won't add the new Motorcycle to mInventory.

OH... and here are the error messages I'm getting...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.Controller.userCreateBike(Controller.java:26)
    ... 55 more
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: I just added the whole list of errors that I'm getting. I'm really at a loss. I mean logically it checks out (I wrote a command line app with almost identical code) but IntelliJ doesn't like it at all. Is it something with the Event Handler?

Comment: I'll also add that as soon as I remove the line `mInventory.addMotorcycle(motorcycle);` the code executes without a problem.

Comment: You're getting a `NullPointerException` when you run the code, so I don't know why you think it has anything to do with your IDE. I assume `mInventory.addMotocycle(...)` is line 26?

Comment: Well, I am new to this so it gets a little confusing. That's correct. It's line 26. What could cause a NullPointerException if  am passing in the object created using the newMotorcycle() method?

Comment: Where do you call the usercreatebike ?

Comment: The error indicates that `mInventory` is `null`, which doesn't make much sense given your code. Make sure all the files are saved and do a clean build of the project (no idea how you do that in IntelliJ but it should be obvious enough).

Comment: I guess if you post the FXML that's the only thing from stopping others from testing your code. And in IntelliJ, from the Build menu, try "Rebuild Project"

Comment: @YassinHajaj userCreateAction method takes an ActionEvent. It only executes when the user hits the submit button after filling in the required TextFields for Motorcycle. It should add the bike to the inventory.

Comment: Please change the access modifier of your List<moto> and try to Check if it is null before adding the object, sysout the BOOLEAN for example

Comment: Well, I downloaded IntelliJ, copied the code into a new project, and ran it, and it ran just fine... Try adding the line `System.out.println(mInventory);` immediately before the line that is generating the error, and see what it does.

Comment: Ok. I added the `System.out.println(mInventory);` and it returns null because it hasn't been populated yet.

Comment: It shouldn't return `null` just because it's not populated. `null` means it's not initialized, which it is by the line `private Inventory mInventory = new Inventory();`. Are you certain the code you have posted here is an exact copy of the code you are running?

Comment: @James_D I just posted all of the code into a new project and it executed without problems. I have no idea what the issue was. I cleaned the code, rebuilt the project, etc. I'll just go with it! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller does not have a constructor, nor the `initialize()` Method.

First define the member `private Inventory mInventory;` at the place where it is now, then create the new object (`mInventory = new Inventory();`) in the constructor or `initialize()` Method.

Comment: Why would that make a difference?

Comment: @James_D Since it doesn't run and we can't see why,  I would have started by changing this to the way it's usually done and proceed from there on.